# How can a custom icon be used in an image menu item?

Tags: python, menu, gtk, pygtk, menuitem

I can create menu items with icons:

```
new = gtk.ImageMenuItem(gtk.STOCK_NEW, 'New')
```

but how can I use a custom icon - from a file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> http://library.gnome.org/devel/pygtk/stable/class-gtkimagemenuitem.html#method-gtkimagemenuitem--set-image

```
img = gtk.Image()
img.set_from_file(filename)
new = gtk.ImageMenuItem(gtk.STOCK_NEW, 'New')
new.set_image(img)
```

Comment: Hi, also add `new.set_always_show_image(True)` in order to make the image show since it is switched off by default. [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/94378/imagemenuitem-icons-in-python-appindicator)

Answer (score 1):

For me the following code worked:

```
img = gtk.Image()
img.set_from_stock(gtk.STOCK_NEW, 1)
item = gtk.ImageMenuItem('New')
item.set_image(img)
menu.append(item)
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* it addresses the question.  Without that, your answer has much less educational value - remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.